# MongoDB + OData: Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression: <ConditionalExpression>

Tags: c#, mongodb, kendo-ui, mongodb-.net-driver, asp.net-web-api-odata

I'am trying to implement a simple log viewer using the KendoUI grid, MongoDB and OData (using Microsoft.Data.OData).
An "eq" query works fine for date and strings, but if I use something else like "substringof" I get an exception:
`Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression: <ConditionalExpression>`
Full stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/UGmwdt0F
Here is the code I'am using:

```
public class LogMessagesController : ODataController
{
    [Queryable(PageSize = 10)]
    public IQueryable<LogMessage> Get()
    {
        IQueryable<LogMessage> container =  Databases.GetLoggingDatabase().GetCollection<LogMessage>("LogMessages").AsQueryable();
        return container;
    }
}

public class LogMessage
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string LogLevel { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public Guid ApiKey { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: ever found solution for this?

Comment: stuck on  this issue for days now

Comment: Sorry, never solved this issue.

Comment: I was abel to fix it. Let me know if u need it

Comment: @Raas can you post the fix please? Stuck on this too

Comment: @RaasMasood could you please provide your solution?